# Тире в простых предложениях

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить тире в предложении "OOO "Рога и копыта" к вашим услугам" после ООО "Рога и копыта"? В данном предложении "к вашим услугам" является сказуемым или это неполное предложение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OOO "Рога и копыта" к вашим услугам.**

Это **эллиптическое предложение вида подлежащее ― дополнение**, сравнить: OOO "Рога и копыта" для вас.

Тире в таких случаях факультативно, ставится при наличии паузы, в этом предложении пауза не делается.